# UIButton Touch Event - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, button, uibutton, touch

My buttons often do not notice the touch. Some causes?

```
let button = UIButton(type: .system)
button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

Comment: did you add the button target?

Comment: Yes. Touchupinside and touchdown but it is the same story

Comment: add `button.layer.borderWidth = 1`and `button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor`and check the frame of your button is where you think

Comment: It is correct but touch doesn't work well

Comment: You don´t have any other view added with lower zIndex than this button?, no other view is on top in view Hierarchy ?

Comment: there is a scrollview and other views as lines horizontally e vertically.

Comment: can be any of this views stay in front of your button at any point?, can you add frames borders and make sure of that?

Comment: The views were the problem. Thanks very much

Comment: Your welcome @Carlo, happy coding

Answer (score 1):

Set the translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints property of the button to be true: `button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true`

Comment: I have built my page with constraints and so your answer is bad

Comment: Next time mention that you use constraints so people can be more effective in answering.